# Question about $\bar{k}$-rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically integral variety over a number field $k$. Is there a difference between the set $X(\bar{k})$ and the points of the base extension $X \times _k \bar{k}$?

I know that every point $\alpha \in X(\bar{k})$ corresponds to a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\,\bar{k} \rightarrow X$, but if the sets above can be identified with each other, does $\alpha$ identify with a morphism $X \times_k \bar{k} \rightarrow X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say "closed points" here, but yes, there is a natural correspondence between $X(\overline{k})$ and closed points of $X\times_k\overline{k}$.

The easiest way to see this is to reinterpret the closed points of $X\times_k\overline{k}$ as $X_{\overline{k}}(\overline{k})$. Now look at the commutative diagram defining $X_{\overline{k}}$:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_{\overline{k}} @>>> X\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\operatorname{Spec}\overline{k} @>>> \operatorname{Spec} k
\end{CD}$$

For any $k$-morphism $\alpha:\operatorname{Spec}\overline{k}\to X$ we can construct $\beta: \operatorname{Spec}\overline{k}\to X_{\overline{k}}$ from the universal property of the fiber product by noticing that the morphisms $\alpha$ and $id_{\operatorname{Spec} \overline{k}}$ compose correctly with the right and bottom arrow in the diagram. Conversely, given $\beta: \operatorname{Spec}\overline{k}\to X_{\overline{k}}$ you can get $\alpha: \operatorname{Spec}\overline{k}\to X$ by composing with the projection.

Comment: Alright but in the case where $X$ is a curve, would the closed points of $X \times_k \bar{k}$ be just its points?

Comment: @KelvinLian No, the generic point is not closed.

Comment: So the generic point would not be a point of codimension 1?

Comment: The generic point of a curve is of codimension zero. (Why are you bringing that up now? It doesn't seem very related to your question.)

Comment: Just being curious, thanks for you help, as always.